# Using an SQL parameter for the operator in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL input parameters in a stored procedure to select different rows with various `WHERE` clauses. This is being done using dropdown lists in a view. The issue is that I am allowing the user to select the operator in the where clause using a dropdownlist.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SingleClauseReport
    @selectedRows varchar(1000),
    @testLeftInput varchar(100),
    @testOperatorInput varchar(10),
    @testRightInput varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    Select @selectedRows
    from Test
    where @testLeftInput + ' ' + @testOperatorInput + ' ' + @testRightInput;
END
GO
```

I am getting an error stating that a condition is expected. Is it possible to do this? Otherwise I would just have to use one operator, like:

```
where @testLeftInput = @testRightInput;
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying won't work. You have two options: dynamic sql, or a re-writing the procedure to have one query for each possible operator and then decide which to execute based on the parameter. I strongly recommend the latter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SingleClauseReport
    @selectedRows varchar(1000),
    @testLeftInput varchar(100),
    @testOperatorInput varchar(10),
    @testRightInput varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  If @testOperatorInput  = '=' 
  Begin
    Select @selectedRows
    from Test
    where @testLeftInput = @testRightInput;
  End
  Else If @testOperatorInput  = '>' 
  Begin
    Select @selectedRows
    from Test
    where @testLeftInput > @testRightInput;
  End
  --...
END
```

Comment: Be careful of performance problems using this approach. Without a couple of additional things this can suffer greatly from cached execution plans. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to figure out the least costly way to use this strategy with an `AND` in the `WHERE` clause (So there would be two operators), but that may be enough for another question

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
AS
BEGIN

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = N'Select ' + @selectedRows 
+ ' from Test where ' + @testLeftInput + ' ' 
+ @testOperatorInput + ' ' 
+  @testRightInput;

execute sp_executesql @sql

END
```

Comment: I would highly advise you NOT to use this method. It is wide open to sql injection. This is pretty much a textbook example of how sql injection works.